# When bikepacking solo, how to handle luggage when shopping?

Tags: bikes, solo, bikepacking

I'm planning my first solo cycling trip this summer. While it's not my first cycling trip (I've already done 4 big ones over 1000 km), it's the first tour I'm planning to do alone. One thing concerns me a lot, is how it works with shopping. So far, we've always handled it by having one person wait with the luggage while the other person does the shopping. But how do I do that alone and what are your experiences? Countries on the route are Belgium, Netherlands, and France.