# How do I calculate how many days I need for a bike tour?

Tags: bikepacking, solo

I'm currently planning roughly the stages of a 1400 km long bike tour in order to book trains to the starting point and away from the destination. I have planned 24 days (including rest days) for the 1400 km now. How do you estimate the duration of your tours?

In my [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/29590/when-bikepacking-solo-how-to-handle-luggage-when-shopping) before I learnd so much! Thanks!!!

Comment: How much long distance experience do you have and is that in a comparable hilly/flat area?